# 'vertices' does not exist on type 'BufferGeometry' in threejs

Tags: three.js

I am using three.js library for drawing an image to the screen. When I create my plainGeometry typescript says that vertices does not exist in particles.geometry.vertices, but when I run my module everything loads and responds as it should besides it gives me this error saying vertices does not exists, and if they did not exist I would not have drawn that image.

Geometry has a property that is called vertices, and when I create the object particles through three.point(geometry, material); I get all the vertices from geometry and access them by doing this.particles.geometry.vertices, but typescript says the property does not exist in geometry even though it works

this is error showing

> Property 'vertices' does not exist on type 'PlaneGeometry'.

below is the code which i did.Can u please help me to solve this problem

**CODE:**
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-threejs-demo-basic-hhtztu

Answer (score 4):

Since `r125` all geometry generators like `PlaneGeometry` are derived from `BufferGeometry`. In the same release, `Geometry` has been removed meaning `BufferGeometry` is the only way to work with geometry data now.

That means you can't access the `vertices` property anymore. The usual approach for implementing a simple vertex displacement like in your code is:

```js
const positionAttribute = geometry.getAttribute('position');

for (let i = 0; i < positionAttribute.count; i ++) {

    vertex.fromBufferAttribute(positionAttribute, i);

    const waveX1 = 0.25 * Math.sin(v.x * 2 + t * 3)
    const waveX2 = 0.125 * Math.sin(v.x * 3 + t * 2)
    const waveY1 = 0.1 * Math.sin(v.y * 5 + t * 0.5)
    
    vertex.z = (waveX1 + waveX2 + waveY1);

    positionAttribute.setZ(i, vertex.z);


}

positionAttribute.needsUpdate = true;
```

Comment: i added above code but shoing error Property 'getAttribute' does not exist on type 'Geometry | BufferGeometry'.If possible can u please implement that in my above code please

Comment: Please upgrade `three.js` to the latest version. Besides, TS declaration files are now available here: https://github.com/three-types/three-ts-types